# C++ Socket Receiving Erroneous Commands, not intended ones

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am learning socket programming for use in an upcoming project, and I have researched the issue pretty extensively. Basically, all this program needs to is on a client computer (locally, i.e. my computer) needs to connect to a remote server and send a command (which it has done, I have gotten it to read back Apache server stats to me).

What is happening is this: I believe I have the socket set right, but the server receives random garbage buffers (one of which consisted of " '>Z"). I have tried various socket settings, different bindings, etc.

I have in the process of starting it will initialize winsock, create a socket, bind the network, and then do a listen loop and while(1) recv data.

I have yet to get the server (on a remote computer, hosted at a datacenter) to output the message. This is my only goal for the time being. I appreciate everyone's help in advance, and the code is before (this is the entire code, sorry for the length).

Client Code:

```
char *host = "127.0.0.1";
        SOCKET clientsock;
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;

        struct hostent *host_info;

        WSADATA WSAData;
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData) != -1) {
            cout << "WINSOCK2 Initialized" << endl;         
            if((clientsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cout << "Socket Created" << endl;

                char opt[2];
                opt[0] = 0;
                opt[1] = 1;

                //setsockopt(clientsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, opt, sizeof(opt));

                host_info = gethostbyname(host);                    

                server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
                server_address.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host_info->h_addr);                   
                server_address.sin_port = htons(80);

                if(connect(clientsock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == 0) {
                    cout << "Connected to host" << endl;
                    char COMMAND[22] = "SVR --WINSOCK-VERIFY\0";
                    if(send(clientsock, COMMAND, sizeof(COMMAND), 0)) {
                        cout << "Command Sent" << endl;                         
                        closesocket(clientsock);
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "ERROR - Could not send command. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                        closesocket(clientsock);
                        WSACleanup();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    cout << "ERROR - Could not connect to host. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                    closesocket(clientsock);
                    WSACleanup();
                }                   
            }
            else {
                cout << "ERROR - Could not create the socket. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                  
                WSACleanup();
            }               
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR - Could not initialize WINSOCK2. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                                
            WSACleanup();
        }
```

Server Code:

```
SOCKET serversock;
        char *server = "127.0.0.1";     
        //char *server = "50.31.1.180"; 
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;

        WSADATA WSAData;
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WSAData) != -1) {
            cout << "WINSOCK2 Initialized" << endl;

            if((serversock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, PF_UNSPEC)) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
                cout << "Socket Created" << endl;

                unsigned long NB = 1;
                ioctlsocket(serversock, FIONBIO, &NB);

                server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
                server_address.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server);
                server_address.sin_port = htons(21578); 

                if(bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr) == 0)) {
                    cout << "Network bound" << endl;                    

                    cout << "Listening..." << endl;
                    listen(serversock, 5);                      
                    while(1) {                  
                        int size = sizeof((struct sockaddr *)server);
                        SOCKET clientsock = accept(serversock, (struct sockaddr *)server, &size);
                        char INCOMMAND[20];
                        if(clientsock >= 0) { 
                            if(recv(clientsock, INCOMMAND, sizeof(INCOMMAND), 0)) {                             
                                int i = 0;  
                                if(INCOMMAND == "SVR --WINSOCK-VERIFY\0") {
                                    cout << "SVR receieved" << endl;
                                }
                                while(INCOMMAND[i] != '\0') {
                                    cout << INCOMMAND[i];                                       
                                    i++;                                                                            
                                }                                   
                                cout << endl;                                   
                            }
                            else {
                                cout << "ERROR - Could not receive command" << endl;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }                       
                }
                else {
                    cout << "ERROR - Could not bind network. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                    closesocket(serversock);
                    WSACleanup();
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "ERROR - Could not create the socket. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                  
                WSACleanup();
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR - Could not initialize WINSOCK2. " << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                                
            WSACleanup();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `send`/`recv` may not send/receive the amount of bytes you indicate in their third argument, in fact, most of the time they will send/receive less bytes than you expect. You usually have to loop until the entire data has been sent/received. Also note that doing this:

```
char buffer[100];
recv(clientsock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
cout << buffer;
```

Will most surelly print garbage, since you don't have a null terminator in your char array(whatch out for buffer overflows when appending it), and you're not checking the return value of recv. It might be reading 1 byte only(or none if an error ocurred). You're printing your buffer the same way in your server app.

In this case, you are actually sending the null-terminator, but since you might read less bytes than you expect, this character might not be received by the other application, thus printing it will print garbage chars.

**Edit**: You should have a look at the structure of a `sockaddr` struct. You can have a look at it [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html). In your code you are using this convertion:

```
int size = sizeof((struct sockaddr *)"127.0.0.1");
```

`const char *`, which is the type of "127.0.0.1", cannot be casted to a sockaddr pointer, they're incompatible. Here you should use `getaddrinfo` in order to resolve the IP address(note that you could use a domain name, and this function would resolve it). There are lots of tutorials online on how to use this function, just search for "getaddrinfo".

Comment: Thank you fontanini. I have included a null character (\0) in the string and used a loop to sort through it on the server side. The program still beleives it is receiving commands, although it is only garbage data. My issue is now this: with the corrected code (which I have edited in the post originally), now running on localhost for the purpose of testing, will not deliver the command. The client side reads back that is properly connected and sent the command, yet the server shows no sign of it ever coming in. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the 'man' page but in fact a blocking `send()` will send the entire message, blocking if necessary until it can do so.

Comment: @EJP The man page does mention that. However, MSDN states "If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter.". Therefore it is correct to loop while sending, unless you want your code to be platform dependent. BTW, OP is using Windows, therefore the loop-while-sending is correct.

Comment: Fontanini, I have once edited the code in my original post. I have changed the character format that casts to the struct to match its requested type, being char.  Now, the code still does work, and I am little lost on how exactly sure how to utilize the getaddrinfo() function. I am still somewhat new to C++, I'm sorry, and I appreciate your help.

Additionally, I am not receiving non-garbage repeating values such as PBR from the server monitor window.

Comment: You're still using sockaddr structs wrong. I'd recommend you to read this tutorial: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html . It's a great tutorial and it explains how to handle sockaddr structs, connections, bind, and everything you need to make it work.

Comment: Fontanini, thank you for all your help. I will read this, and revise my code. For now, I consider this question answered.